# 'This' is undefined inside subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a subscribe statement and I am trying to debug this however when I step through in VS Code 'this' is always undefined inside the statement. In this situation 'this.dataLoaded' is undefined. how can I get it to not be undefined when debugging?

```
this.router.events
            .filter(event => (event instanceof NavigationEnd))
                .subscribe((routeData: any) => {                        
                    if(!this.dataLoaded){
                      ...
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code, or link to stackblitz with full solution?  There's nothing to go on here.

Comment: It's likely that it's been rewritten to `_this` or something like that during the transpilation. Look at the "Locals" or "Scope" section of your debugging interface and look for other items in scope.

Comment: Hi Terrance is normal because you are in the this which is the event instead  the global scope this, try this  const me = this , outside off the this.router and then !me.dataLoaded

Comment: @AmericoArvani There is no local `this` because the `subscribe` is using an arrow function.

Comment: Correct the local this is undefined only when debugging. It works fine if the code just runs. I just need to know if there is a way that I can see the local 'this' inside the subscribe when debugging. @Daniel Giminez there is no surrounding code. This could be an interview question one day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `.subscribe()` then in angular it may possible that it'll not getting `this`. In my case I used another replica of this. It always works for me. It may for you also.

```
var that = this; // Hear I store the this ref into another that
this.router.events
        .filter(event => (event instanceof NavigationEnd))
            .subscribe((routeData: any) => {                        
                if(!that.dataLoaded){  // Hear you can use that instead of this
                  ...
                }
            });
```

Comment: I stumbled across this, can you explain why?

Comment: Please see the response from My Stack Overfloweth, below - that/this is no longer the recommended route

Comment: @ParsaGachkar answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: As answered by My Stack Overfloweth, there is now a better way to do this using arrow functions. This is currently the best approach to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look on `closure` expand sections in debugger `variables` tab. Your real `this` will be one level above the top-most, where `this` is referred to component controller name. Each anonymous function creates additional closure, in your case it's enclosed in `subscribe`, ant this closure will be opened by default by VS Code when your breakpoint will be hit.

And please try to avoid this old-style JS hacking `let that = this` e.c.t, because when you on TypeScript, Classes, ES6 and arrow functions those hacks are just not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who was close to implementing the `that = this` route from the accepted answer, save yourself and look into the answer Tomas wrote. It's good to spend some extra time on and to avoid using javascript hacks if possible.

For an example in using arrow functions to keep your `this` context, see below.

This is the code I originally had which lost the `this` context:

```
this.settingsService.getClientSettingsByCategory(clientId, categoryId)
    .subscribe(
        this.loadJobStatusReport
    );
```

And this is the updated code which keeps the expected `this` context:

```
this.settingsService.getClientSettingsByCategory(clientId, categoryId)
    .subscribe(
        settings => this.loadJobStatusReport(settings)
    );
```

Comment: What is settings that you are passing?

Comment: The return value of our "getClientSettingsByCategory" method. Which is an array of "Setting" objects.

Comment: Perfect - that makes sense. Thanks for making it clear, especially on the that/this debate.

Comment: sorry but this dose not work for me, instead that/this works. iam still searching for better way then that/this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is a good idea or not. I'm a beginner. but You could use the `.bind(this)` method.

here is an angular ts example:

```
this.myService.getData().subscribe((data=>{
    this.doSomething(data);
    alert(this.somethingElse);
}).bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it makes a huge difference between

```
a.subscribe(function(x){ ... }) // <-- here this is bound to a
```

and

```
a.subscribe(x => { ... }) // <-- here this is the class where we're in
```

So I use the second one all the time and thus don't need to use something like `var self = this`